# Changing the axis of a chart sheet with macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to change the values of a chart axis autumatically with macro from a cell. I can get it to work, if the command button and chart are on the same sheet. But I'd like to change it on chart, that is not in a normal sheet, but in a "chart sheet", so reference to is a little bit different. Does anyone now how?

```
Sub ChangeAxisScale()
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chart21").Chart
    With .Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_max").Value
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Axis_min").Value
        .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("Unit").Value
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That code is incomplete. I see two `End With`. Did you forget to paste something?

Comment: Yes, I have forgot. The 2ns line which enables to do this on the same sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use appropriate references. For example (**Untested**)

```
Sub ChangeAxisScale()
    Dim wsChart As Chart
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet

    '~~> Change the below as applicable
    Set wsChart = Chart1 '<~~ Code name of the chart sheet
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Name of sheet with data

    With wsChart
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MaximumScale = wsInput.Range("Axis_max").Value
            .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("Axis_min").Value
            .MajorUnit = wsInput.Range("Unit").Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Charts("Chart Name") ' may be more reliable than code name.

Comment: `Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Charts("Chart Name") ' may be more reliable than code name. –  Jon Peltier 3 mins ago` @JonPeltier: Hmmm, Interesting... I know for sure that you are the charts guru and maybe I am missing something here but I would like to know why do you think the name of the chart is better than the code name... considering that the chart's name can change but not the code name of the chart.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessarily more reliable to use an existing code name. But in most cases you do not have access to the user's VB Project, and so you cannot change the code name to something memorable ("Chart1" is not memorable). And while the code name of a chart is not as easy to change as the sheet name, it can be changed, and if the user copies the chart sheet, the new sheet has a new code name.